# Why is the zIndex sequence of my objects not what I expected?

Tags: konvajs

How can I get a list of all objects with all params (x, y, width, etc.), including zIndex param on the stage after completing resizing? And how can I set an zIndex for each object when creating a stage?

I have this code, but setZIndex not working correctly. Images are not set correctly.

```
const oKonvaStage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'dropzone'
});

const oKonvaLayer = new Konva.Layer();
oKonvaStage.add(oKonvaLayer);

const oKonvaImage1 = new Konva.Image({
    x: 624,
    y: 433,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1280
});

const oImage1 = new Image();
oImage1.onload = function() {
    oKonvaImage1.image(oImage1);
    oKonvaLayer.add(oKonvaImage1);
    oKonvaImage1.setZIndex(2);
    oKonvaLayer.draw();
};

oImage1.src = 'image1.jpg';

oKonvaImage1.on('transformend', function(e) {
    UpdateAttrs();
});

const oKonvaImage2 = new Konva.Image({
    x: 9,
    y: 254,
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024
});

const oImage2 = new Image();
oImage2.onload = function() {
    oKonvaImage2.image(oImage2);
    oKonvaLayer.add(oKonvaImage2);
    oKonvaImage2.setZIndex(0);
    oKonvaLayer.draw();
};

oImage2.src = 'image2.jpg';

oKonvaImage2.on('transformend', function(e) {
    UpdateAttrs();
});

const oKonvaImage3 = new Konva.Image({
    x: -586,
    y: -315,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1199
});

const oImage3 = new Image();
oImage3.onload = function() {
    oKonvaImage3.image(oImage3);
    oKonvaLayer.add(oKonvaImage3);
    oKonvaImage3.setZIndex(1);
    oKonvaLayer.draw();
};

oImage3.src = 'image3.jpg';
```

Image3 has index = 1 but is over Image2 which has index = 2.

Comment: For z-index read the [docs here](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/groups_and_layers/zIndex.html). For the dump of the objects overall, iterate the layers, use layer.getChildren() to get the child objects of the layer, use child.getClassName() to get the type of each child, and use getChildren again on any that are group types.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Thanks for advice, but zIndex still not set correctly. I edited my post and I added the code.

Comment: Hey did you see the answer I updated below?

Answer (score 1):

First off, prompted by @lavrton's comment, you should add the konva.Images to the canvas as soon as you have instantiated them - not in the image onload event. The image objects are no overhead to the canvas, and you can then be sure of the initial z-index sequence. You may change the sequence after that, but at least you start with a known layout.

And as a general rule, you need to take care when using any commands inside the onload event of an image. Image loading is asynchronous - meaning it does not happen in the sequence you might anticipate when you write the code. A large image coming from a slow server will load more slowly than a small image from a quick server, but you cannot make any assumptions about the sequence. The ONLY way you can ensure the sequence is to have the load of the second image initiated from the onload event of the first, but this is generally going to give bad UX.

Back to the code you posted, the code in my snippet below would appear to work as you intended. I switched the ECMA2015 const to plain old vars, and removed the unnecessary on-transforms.

I also added some code to analyse the results, showing the hoped-for zIndex value and the achieved zIndex values.

Note that the zIndex value in Konva is relative to the parent container and not absolute. 
 So, for example, when I set zondex=999 I actually get a value of 4.

Summary:

- avoid calling code for which sequence is critical in onload events.
- do not expect to get exactly the zindex you ask for.

```js
var div = $('#dropzone');
var oKonvaStage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'dropzone', width: div.width(), height: div.height()});

var indexWanted = [];

   
var oKonvaLayer = new Konva.Layer();
oKonvaStage.add(oKonvaLayer);

var oKonvaImage1 = new Konva.Image({
    name: 'image-1',
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    width: 300,
    height: 100
});

var oImage1 = new Image();
oImage1.onload = function() {
    oKonvaLayer.add(oKonvaImage1);
    oKonvaImage1.image(oImage1);
    oKonvaImage1.setZIndex(2);
    indexWanted[0] = 2;
    oKonvaLayer.draw();
    sayPos();
};

oImage1.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/300x100/666/fff.png?text=Image-1'


var oKonvaImage2 = new Konva.Image({
    name: 'image-2',
    x: 10,
    y: 100,
    width: 300,
    height: 100
});

var oImage2 = new Image();
oImage2.onload = function() {
    oKonvaImage2.image(oImage2);
    oKonvaLayer.add(oKonvaImage2);
    oKonvaImage2.setZIndex(0);
    indexWanted[1] = 0;
    oKonvaLayer.draw();
    sayPos();
};

oImage2.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/300x100/333/fff.png?text=Image-2';

var oKonvaImage3 = new Konva.Image({
    name: 'image-3',
    x: 280,
    y: 80,
    width: 300,
    height: 100
});

var oImage3 = new Image();
oImage3.onload = function() {
    oKonvaImage3.image(oImage3);
    oKonvaLayer.add(oKonvaImage3);
    oKonvaImage3.setZIndex(999);  //  <<<< notice this is set to 99. Compare to console output !!
    indexWanted[2] = 999;
    oKonvaLayer.draw();
    sayPos();
};

oImage3.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc/fff.png?text=Image-3';

oKonvaLayer.draw();
oKonvaStage.draw();

var picCnt = 0, s= '', imgNo = 0;
function sayPos(){
  picCnt = picCnt + 1;
  if (picCnt === 3){
    for (var i = 0; i < indexWanted.length; i = i + 1){
      imgNo = i + 1;
      s = s + '<br/>Image-' + imgNo + ' zindex wanted = ' + indexWanted[i]  + ' actual zIndex=' +   oKonvaLayer.findOne('.image-' + imgNo).getAbsoluteZIndex();
    }
  $('#info').html(s)

    
  }

}
```

```css
#info {
font-size: 10pt;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<p id='info' >
</p>
<div id='dropzone' style="position: absolute; top: 90px; z-index: -1; display: inline-block; left: 0px;  width: 600px; height: 400px; background-color: silver;"></div>
```

Comment: I think it will be even better to set zIndex and add `Konva.Image` into the layer BEFORE onload event (right after instance initialization).

Comment: I am going to add a warning into `setZIndex` function for invalid values (like 99 is not expected value).

Comment: @lavrton - I would leave it as it is - its not broken. On a different note, I found that using node.zIndex() to retrieve the node zindex within a getChildren() function caused an error. I could see that being an issue for groups and layers. Of course for the stage we can use getAbsoluteZindex() as in my snippet.